# String message of an SMS

Tags: android, string, sms, message

I am learning how to develop Apps on Android.
I have a button that onClick, it should read my SMS and check the body of each SMS, if one SMS contains "WORD" then DO something.

It should be achieved using this, right?

```
 String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();



                while (body.contains("WORD"))
                   DO SOMETHING
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Is there any way to do this without hitting the button, progamatically every hour for example?

Comment: do you wanna check with new message or with all messages in inbox..??

Comment: youcan use timer for every button and do button.performclick so user doesnt have to click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want ot check it with new message you need to create BroadcastReceiver

AndroidManifest.xml Declaration :

```
<receiver android:name=".MySMSReceiver "> 
<intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

BroadcastReceiver :

```
public class MySMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceiver(Context context, Intent intent) {

   Object[] pdus=(Object[])intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
   String sender="";

   StringBuilder text=new StringBuilder();

   // get sender from first PDU
   SmsMessage shortMessage=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);

   sender=shortMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

   for (int i=0;i<pdus.length;i++) {
       shortMessage=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
       text.append(shortMessage.getDisplayMessageBody());
   }

   while (text.contains("WORD")) {
       // DO SOMETHING 
   }

   Log.d("SMSReceiver","SMS message sender: " + shortMessage.getOriginatingAddress());
   Log.d("SMSReceiver","SMS message text: " + shortMessage.getDisplayMessageBody());
 }
}
```

Comment: Hello, THIS is what I have, what should I put into? thank you!

Comment: `last = (Button) findViewById(R.id.last);
        last.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


      String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();



                while (body.contains("WORD"))
                   DO SOMETHING


            }
        });`

Answer (score 1):

instead of while you need to use an if statement...
    `if (body.contains("WORD"){
                   DO SOMETHING
                              }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)  to schedule some task to be run at some point in the future

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8801990/1051147 for example